# Twitter share image not showing

Tags: php, image, twitter, share

I want to share Image , Text and Url on Twitter through php.
I used "Summary Card with Large Image". For this added all meta tag, but not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
    <meta charset="utf-8" />  
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />  
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="Summary Card Implementation" />  
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="This describes about Twitter Summary Card" />  
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/11/29/15/59/tower-5788197_960_720.jpg" />  
  
    <style>  
        body{background: #148c6b;color: #fff;font-family: calibri;font-size: 16px;}  
        a.tweet{color:#fff; padding:6px 20px; background:#ff6600;margin-top:40px;text-decoration:none; border-radius:5px;}  
    </style>  
      
</head>  
  
<body>  
    <h1>Twitter Summary Card</h1>  
    <p>Summary Card Implementaion on Web Page</p>  
    <div>  
        <a class="twitter-share-button"  
           href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://www.example.com?sid=12">  
            Tweet  
        </a>  
    </div>  
  
    <script>  
        //Twitter widget script to render tweet button
        window.twttr = (function (d, s, id) {  
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],  
              t = window.twttr || {};  
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;  
            js = d.createElement(s);  
            js.id = id;  
            js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";  
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);  
  
            t._e = [];  
            t.ready = function (f) {  
                t._e.push(f);  
            };  
  
            return t;  
        }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));</script>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Please help me with possible solution.
Thanks..

Comment: Hi, can you share your codes?